# AngularJS : Update filter for UI Grid from external method

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like to be able to set/update a value in my controller that is then filtered in the grid. Currently, the changes to the filter aren't updated until I type into the grid which then triggers the filterChanged event. Any idea of how I can automatically filter the data in my grid config or at least do a hard refresh?

Thank you for the help.

Here's a slightly modified Plunker from the AngularJS UI Grid website. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/pgX31NT3Ry3XllZ3JO2B?p=preview

Here's my current filter definition in the columnDefs section:

```
    { field: 'company', filter: {
    noTerm: true,
    condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
      return cellValue == scope.term;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

When you define your `gridOptions`, set the gridAPI variable with the following:

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
},
```

And then in your update function, run the following to re-evaluate the filter condition:

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.refresh()
```

As @Conan mentioned, a breaking update was released and this works only in

There was a bug and this doesn't work on 3.2.x. Tested and works in 3.1.x and 4.x
http://plnkr.co/edit/YbgV9YZrWCZE4cc3qGru?p=preview

Comment: Starting from version 3.2.1, refresh() no longer triggers the event that causes the grid to re-evaluate the custom filter function. Only putting text in the filter box triggers that event.

Comment: Updating the plunkr... I haven't experimented with the API in quite some time, there may be something else available now

Comment: Like you said, I think it is a issue with the new release of ui grid.

Comment: This is working for me in v.3.2.7, though the docs have not yet been updated.

Comment: @Guus working since 4.x for me. Updating the plunkr again